# Printing Half Pyramid of Numbers

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

```
public class NestedForLoop {

    private void generateNumberPyramid(int num) {
        int length = num + 1;

        for(int i = 1; i < length; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print(j+1);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NestedForLoop nfl = new NestedForLoop();
        nfl.generateNumberPyramid(4);
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
1
12
123
1234
```

The intended output should be:

```
1
22
333
4444
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `i` corresponds to each row. `i=1` refers to the first row, `i=2` refers to the second row and so on.  Therefore in your `for loop`, make the following change:

```
for(int i = 1; i < length; i++) {

        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Ideone link: http://ideone.com/5g0xWT

Comment: I think you didn't pick up the code from your Ideone. You still have him printing out j+1.

Comment: @pens-fan-69: Sorry, something else was copied to clipboard and I didn't notice :)

Answer (score 3):

Change `System.out.print(j+1);` for `System.out.print(i);`

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.print(i)` instead of `System.out.print(j+1)`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the nested for loop:

Change:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    System.out.print(j+1);
}
```

To:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are iterating the ROWS, you should use i and not (j+1). Doing this will simply iterate what you want, otherwise it will keep adding one to each number. so just like this:

```
     for(int i = 1; i < length; i++) {

        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```